# The real sequence $x_0=a, \text{and} ~x_{n+1}=\frac{1}{4}+x_n-(x_n)^2 \text{ for $n\geq 1$}.$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Define the real sequence $x_0=a$ and $x_{n+1}=\frac{1}{4}+x_n-(x_n)^2$ for $n\geq 1$. Which of the following statements is/are true?

$1$. If $a=0$, then the sequence $x_n$ is convenient to $\frac{1}{2}$.

$2.$If $a=0$, then the sequence $x_n$ is divergent.

$3.$ If $a\in\left(-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{2}\right)$, then the sequence $x_n$ is convenient to $\frac{1}{2}$.

$4.$ If $a=0$, then the sequence $x_n$ is convenient to $-\frac{1}{2}$.

I can confirm that option one is true, and as a result, options two and four are false. This is because the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{4}+x-x^2$ is increasing for $x<\frac{1}{2}$. If we begin with $x=0$, the sequence becomes monotonically increasing and is bounded above by $\frac{1}{2}$, thus converging to $\frac{1}{2}$. However, I'm uncertain about option three. Can you please provide some guidance? Thank you.

Comment: For option 3.,$$x_1 = \frac14 + a - a^2 = \frac14 + (1-a) -(1-a)^2$$ so the cases when $x_0=a\in\left(\frac12, \frac32\right)$ behaves just like if $x_0 = 1-a$ instead. Then judge if your argument for option 1. still works for $a\in\left(-\frac12, \frac12\right)$.

Comment: What does it mean for a sequence to be convenient to a number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$x_{n+1}-\frac{1}{2} = -\left(x_n^2 -x_n+\frac{1}{4}  \right) =-\left(x_n -\frac{1}{2}  \right)^2 $$
We deduce then the closed-form expression of $x_n $

$$\color{red}{x_n =\frac{1}{2} -\left(a -\frac{1}{2}  \right)^{2^n}} \tag{1}$$

From $(1)$, it's easy to deduce that only the statements $1$ and $3$ hold true.

Comment: thank you........

Comment: @neelkanth You're welcome!

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

First, try to get rid of the constant

$$x_n=y_n+k\quad \implies \quad y_{n+1}+y_n^2+(2k-1)y_n+\left(k^2-\frac 14\right)=0$$ So,
$$k=\frac 12 \quad \implies \quad y_{n+1}+y_n^2=0$$

Now $$y_n=-u_n\quad \implies \quad u_{n+1}=u_n^2$$
$$u_n=e^{v_n}\quad \implies \quad e^{v_{n+1}}=e^{2v_{n}}\quad \implies \quad v_{n+1}=2v_{n}$$  Now, the problem is simple.

Comment: thank you......

Answer (score 2):

From $$x_{n+1}=\frac 14+x_n-(x_n)^2$$ you get $$x_{n+1}-x_n=\frac 14-{x_n}^2$$

It follows almost instantly, that for the starting point

1. below $-\frac 12$, the sequence is decreasing and divergent to $-\infty$;
2. equal $-\frac 12$, it remains constant at $a=-\frac 12$;
3. in $\left(-\frac 12,\frac 12\right)$, it's increasing, but at no point it jumps over $\frac 12$;
4. equal $\frac 12$, it remains constant at $a=\frac 12$;
5. above $\frac 12$, it jumps below $\frac 12$.

If we analyze the $x_1$ value after the first step in case 5. it turns out that

- for $a\in\left(\frac 12, \frac 32\right)$ we get $x_1 > -\frac 12$;
- for $a=\frac 32$ the sequence gets locked at $-\frac 12$;
- and for bigger values of $a$ it drops below $-\frac 12$ and diverges to $-\infty$.

Finally,

- $a\in\left(-\frac 12,\frac 32\right)$ makes the sequence convergent to $\frac 12$,
- $a\in\left\{-\frac 12,\frac 32\right\}$ makes it convergent to $-\frac 12$,
- otherwise $(x_n)$ diverges to minus infinity.

Comment: Thank you......

Answer (score 1):

Please note that what follows is not a rigorous formal  proof. But the idea is very often introduced in dynamical systems textbooks. It provides an worthwhile alternative approach.
$$$$
[image]

$$$$
Draw the graphs of $$y=\frac{1}{4}+x-x^2$$
and $$y=x$$ as shown.

It can be seen that starting from any point $x_1=a$ where $-\frac{1}{2} \lt a \lt \frac{3}{2}$ and follows the path of the red lines as shown,

the sequence $\{x_n \}$ will converge to $0.5$.

Comment: Thank you ......